# NSManagedObjects with like properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView` that displays the value of a property called `name` of an `NSManagedObject` using `CoreData`. I have it working by just using a basic `NSFetchRequest` and then displaying the value of `name` in the `UITableViewCell`'s `textLabel`.

However, many of the `NSManagedObject`'s have the same `name` value, so I get duplicates in my table. How can I filter it so that I only have one of each `name` value?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your fetch request to only return *distinct values* but that required that you return dictionaries instead of managed objects. Since you are asking for dictionaries you will have to specify what values to return.

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11234058/608157) to [avoid duplicate results on Core Data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11233789/608157).

---

In short:

```
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
```